# Aplicar função por grupos ou fatores no R

Tags: r

Prezadas e prezados,

Preciso calcular o crescimento populacional relativo dos municípios brasileiros, de um ano para o outro (população final menos a população inicial, dividido pela população inicial). Para isso, fiz uma simples função:

```
var_rel <- function(x,y){
  ((x-y)/y)*100
}
```

Em que `x` é a população de 2019 e `y` a população de 2014.

No entanto, não estou conseguindo aplicar um comando que rode a função por município. Isto porque eu preciso garantir que o `x` (população de 2019) e `y` (população de 2014) sejam do mesmo município.

Hoje, minha função é aplicada da seguinte maneira:

```
var_rel(pop[pop$ano=="2019","qtd_pop_mun"], pop[pop$ano=="2014","qtd_pop_mun"])
```

No entanto, pode ocorrer de ser utilizado como `x` a população de 2019 de um município e como `y` a população de 2014 de outro município. Dessa forma, preciso garantir que isso não ocorra.

Tentei usar a função `tapply`, mas como a função que criei `var_rel` possui argumentos `x` e `y`, não sei como incluir ambos na `tapply`.

O meu objeto tem uma coluna pra ano (de 2014 a 2019), outra pro tamanho da população e outra pro código do IBGE de município (5570 municípios do Brasil).

Eu preciso resolver isso utilizando a função que criei para o cálculo da variação relativa, pois em outros momentos terei cálculos mais personalizados, em que haverá necessidade de gerar uma função própria, como já fiz nesse momento.

Obrigado!

```
    ano key_cd7_ibge_mun qtd_pop_mun qtd_pop_est qtd_pop_pais
1  2014          1100015       25652     1748531    202768562
2  2015          1100015       25578     1768204    204450049
3  2016          1100015       25506     1787279    206081432
4  2017          1100015       25437     1805788    207660929
5  2018          1100015       23167     1757589    208494900
6  2019          1100015       22945     1777225    210147125
7  2014          1100023      102860     1748531    202768562
8  2015          1100023      104401     1768204    204450049
9  2016          1100023      105896     1787279    206081432
10 2017          1100023      107345     1805788    207660929
11 2018          1100023      106168     1757589    208494900
12 2019          1100023      107863     1777225    210147125
13 2014          1100031        6424     1748531    202768562
14 2015          1100031        6355     1768204    204450049
15 2016          1100031        6289     1787279    206081432
16 2017          1100031        6224     1805788    207660929
17 2018          1100031        5438     1757589    208494900
18 2019          1100031        5312     1777225    210147125
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(pop[c("pop", "qtd_pop_mun")])` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(pop[c("pop", "qtd_pop_mun")], 20))`?

Comment: "pop" é apenas o nome de objeto, não há nenhuma coluna com esse nome. Editei com as 20 primeiras linhas do objeto e todas as colunas.

Comment: Tem toda a razão, quis dizer `pop[c("ano", etc)]`.

Comment: 1) A coluna `key_cd7_ibge_mun` é o código de município? 2) Só há linhas com `ano == 2014`, pode refazer o exemplo de dados de tal maneira que haja dados de ambos os anos para os mesmos municípios?

Comment: Sim, essa coluna é o código do município. Tenho dados de 2014 até 2019. O mesmo município se repete 6 vezes, uma pra cada ano.

Answer (score 2):

Usando data.table:

```
library(data.table)

dados <- fread(text =
'ano,key_cd7_ibge_mun,qtd_pop_mun,qtd_pop_est,qtd_pop_pais
2014,1100015,25652,1748531,202768562
2015,1100015,25578,1768204,204450049
2016,1100015,25506,1787279,206081432
2017,1100015,25437,1805788,207660929
2018,1100015,23167,1757589,208494900
2019,1100015,22945,1777225,210147125
2014,1100023,102860,1748531,202768562
2015,1100023,104401,1768204,204450049
2016,1100023,105896,1787279,206081432
2017,1100023,107345,1805788,207660929
2018,1100023,106168,1757589,208494900
2019,1100023,107863,1777225,210147125
2014,1100031,6424,1748531,202768562
2015,1100031,6355,1768204,204450049
2016,1100031,6289,1787279,206081432
2017,1100031,6224,1805788,207660929
2018,1100031,5438,1757589,208494900
2019,1100031,5312,1777225,210147125')

> dados[, .(crescimento = (qtd_pop_mun[.N]-qtd_pop_mun[1])/qtd_pop_mun[1]*100), by = key_cd7_ibge_mun]
   key_cd7_ibge_mun crescimento
1:          1100015  -10.552783
2:          1100023    4.863893
3:          1100031  -17.310087
```

*data.table* é ótimo para realizar operações por grupos em grandes tabelas de dados. A sintaxe é similar à de bancos de dados SQL, consulte a vinheta de introdução do pacote para mais informações: `vignette('datatable-intro', 'data.table')`

Um *data.frame* pode ser convertido para *data.table* usando `setDT(seu.data.frame)`, mas é melhor usar `fread` para ler diretamente seu arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Esta é uma solução R base.
Adota a [estratégia `split/apply/combine` de Hadley Wickham](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/plyr.pdf).

A função `var_rel` é reescrita para ter um só argumento.

```
var_rel <- function(x){
  100*(x[2] - x[1])/x[1]
}

i1 <- pop$ano == 2014
i2 <- pop$ano == 2019
sp <- split(pop[i1 | i2, c(1, 3)], pop$key_cd7_ibge_mun[i1 | i2])
sapply(sp, function(DF){
  var_rel(DF[['qtd_pop_mun']])
})
#   1100015    1100023    1100031 
#-10.552783   4.863893 -17.310087
```